# how to get all the groupValue in solr

Tags: solr

in solr i have to get the uniqque values in my 'name' field of my database.

for that reason I read about grouping and  Iget the desored esult

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":16,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"name:И*",
      "group.field":"name",
      "group":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "grouped":{
    "name":{
      "matches":2231,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"ИВАН",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1144,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "obshtina":"ПЛОВДИВ",
                "phone":"032/670309",
                "timestamp":"2013-03-04T08:43:53.553Z"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"ИЛИЯ",
          "doclist":{"numFound":177,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "obshtina":"БРЕЗОВО",
                "phone":"(3191)2265",
                ..............................
```

ANd I get the the first groupValue

```
var  str = xmlhttp.responseText;

                alert (str); //here everything is OK - i get the respone correctly
                var rsp = JSON.parse(str);
                //var rsp = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var srcAutoComp  = new Array();


alert ("grouped:" + rsp.grouped.name.groups[0].groupValue);
```

But it seems that no matter how much i read I cannot find in the response from solr the number of groups so i can get all the goupvalues in a cicle.

f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [group.ngroups](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters) to get the total count of groups.
To get all the group values, you can facet on the field keeping a facet limit of -1 which will ensure you get all the unique group values in the response.

Comment: hey Jayendra now i noticed that unfurtunately I've got 2 groups which are actuay tje same 'Иван' and 'ИВАН' -  do you know how i can amend that

Comment: check if you can lower case the facet field so that the tokens are normalised and unique.